# Is adding bridges or relay helpful inside a censoring region?

Tags: relays, bridge

I'm relatively new to Tor, so sorry for my dumb question.

But is adding bridges, relays, using snowflake(this one is also detectable) or other plugins useful inside a filtering country?
my guess was if I add any of those, it could have a reverse impact on Tor's performance as it sees more points to connect,  however none of those are exit points.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a VPS on a offshore country you can set up a private bridge: https://github.com/Xaqron/tor-private-bridge -- It will work until the censor blacklist the bridge IP/Port.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not mandatory, if it works without them. But the list of bridges is a must in a censored areas. The best ones are your own private ones on VPS wit the proper scrambling

Comment: btw, your answer is vague, at least to me, I was thinking that adding a relay just adds to the route and decrease the speed and chance of reaching an exit node in a non blocking region.  (like an additional peer in traceroute)

Comment: you're understanding it right. So my point is: try without them at first. If it works - then you don't need them. Tor's logic is not an addition, but a mutually exclusive mode: either you're using the bridges **only**, or you're using a standard connection flow

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your country does not block TOR, you are encouraged to run a bridge (obfs4 or SnowFlake) there. You only are not encouraged to run an exit node there if your country censors the Internet. But there is a difference between running a bridge and running an exit node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does and that's why I asked this question. I was thinking it should be useless if not harmful. what's the reason for encouragement?  due to my lack of knowledge, I see it as an extra peer in route to an exit node.

Comment: Also forgot to mention that some ISPs also detect and block tor with Snowflake.